# Browser goes blank when using this session variable

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

I have a session variable which tries to retirve all image file names below:

```
$_SESSION ['fileImage'][] ['name'] = $_FILES ['fileImage'] ['name'];.
```

But if I try an put this session code in the jsno.encode() function below then the browser goes blank, why is this and how can it be fixed so browser does not go blank?

```
var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage'][]) ? $_SESSION ['fileImage'] : null); ?>;
```

Comment: Turn [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) on: `error_reporting(E_ALL);` to see what exactly went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try;

Setter:

```
$_SESSION['fileImage'] = $_FILES['fileImage']['name'];
```

getter ( Js ):

```
var imagename = <?php echo json_encode(isset($_SESSION['fileImage']) ? $_SESSION['fileImage'] : NULL); ?>;
```

Comment: This helps as browser does not go blank. Problem though is that if I try to retrieve multiple file names, then it only displays 1 file name. E.g. If I upload 2 files, ('tulips.png' and bat.png'), then on screen it displays ('tulips.png and tulips.png) for both file names on screen.

Answer (score 0):

This code seems to be problematic to me:

```
(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage'][])
```

using the double square brackets creates a new entry in an array. You should probably give it a name like this :

```
$_SESSION ['fileImage']['data']['name'] = ...
```

and checking if it is set using the name :

```
(isset($_SESSION ['fileImage']['data'])
```

Although I think there would be no point in creating this sub-array, you could just omit it as Sheldon proposed.